migrate from Bitnami to Atlas
I have to migrate from MongoDB packaged with Bitnami (sharded helm chart with 0 shard) to MongoDB Atlas (replicaset or sharded cluster)
Do you know if there is a way to do that ? Does that mean downtime application ? Is there a way to take advantage of the Live Migration functionality offered by Atlas ?

You should talk to Atlas support - they may already know how to do that.

I would suggest mongoexport and mongoimport. Did you check Migrate or Import Data?
